# jQuery iframe loads multiple times

Tags: jquery, iframe, upload, loading

I am creating a script for file uploading using jQuery and iFrame. So, I have a form with id="myform" and target="myframe" and a frame with id="myframe" and name="myframe" . When the user selects a file the form gets automatically submited and after the iframe loads th results I alert them. The problem is that the first time I upload a file I get one alert, the second two, the third time I upload I get three. My code is like

```
$("#myform input").change(function () { 
    alert("submitting");
    $("#myform").submit();
});

$("#myform").submit(function () {
    alert(submited);
    $("#myframe").load(function () {
        alert ("loaded!");
        alert ($(this).contents().text());
    });
});
```

The alerts that I get multiple time is the "loaded!" and the $(this).contents().text()
That means the form gets submitted once and the iframe "loads" more than one times. I validated this through the Chrome Console, where my action file gets called only once per submit. Why is this happening?

Comment: There's no `iframe` involved here. `.load` loads inline content.

Comment: OK. do you know why this is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `.load` call here?

Comment: If you have firebug setup, how many requests go across the wire?

Comment: Do you have an onload method in your iframe tag? Or is it just associated in your jquery script you have above?

Comment: Check above that I mention that through the chrome console I saw that each time the form gets submitted only one request is made. Anyway,  I solved the issue. The iframe loading was set as a callback to the forms submission

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you are adding a new handler for $("#myframe").load each time your form is submitted.

try :

```
$("#myform input").change(function () { 
    alert("submitting");
    $("#myform").submit();
});

$("#myform").submit(function () {
    alert(submited);
    $("#myframe").unbind('load');
    $("#myframe").load(function () {
        alert ("loaded!");
        alert ($(this).contents().text());
    });
});
```

or:

```
$("#myform input").change(function () { 
    alert("submitting");
    $("#myform").submit();
});

$("#myframe").load(function () {
    alert ("loaded!");
    alert ($(this).contents().text());
});

$("#myform").submit(function () {
    alert(submited);
});
```

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking the same. +1